# d3.csv linked GitHub

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to link my .csv stored in github to the my d3 code. 
Does anybody know if there is anything that I'm missing? I was able to do it with LeafLet not with D3. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>

   <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>D3!!</title>
     </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script 
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.3/leaflet.js">
  </script>
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v0.4.min.js"></script>
      <script>

 var outerWidth=500;
 var outerheight=250;
 var margin={left:-50, top:0, right:-50, bottom:0};
 var xColumn="longitude";
 var yColumn="latitude";
 var rColumn="population";
 var peoplePerPixel=1000000;
 var innerWidth=outerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
 var innerHeight=outerheight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

 var svg=d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", outerWidth)
   .attr("height", outerheight);

     var g= svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate (" + margin.left + "," +margin.top +")");
 var xScale= d3.scaleLog()
 .range([0,innerWidth]);
 var yScale= d3.scaleLog()
 .range([innerHeight,0]);
 var rScale= d3.scaleSqrt();

 function render (data){
 xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d){return d[xColumn]; }));
 yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d){return d[yColumn]; }));
 rScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d){return d[xColumn]; })]);

 var circles= svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);
 circles.enter().append("circle");
 circles
   .attr("cx", function(d){ return xScale(d[xColumn]);})
   .attr("cy", function(d){ return yScale(d[yColumn]);})
   .attr("r", function(d){ return rScale(d[rColumn]);});
   circles.exit().remove();
      }

 function type(d) {
   d.latitude=+d.latitude;
   d.longitude=+d.longitude;
   d.population=+d.population;
   return d;
      }


 var data =           


    d3.csv(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Pre60/myTest/master/map_cities.csv",      
       type, render)


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I removed the `var data = ` before your `d3.csv` call and it works that way.

Comment: I don't get an error but it's not working.  I have also added a ; at the end and still doesnt work. Thoughts? d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Pre60/myTest/master/map_cities.csv",  type,  render);

Comment: You are right, its reading the data, it;s just not showing it on the browser:
Object
city
:
"Qal eh-ye Now"
city_ascii
:
"Qal eh-ye"
country
:
"Afghanistan"
iso2
:
"AF"
iso3
:
"AFG"
latitude
:
34.98300013
longitude
:
63.13329964
population
:
2997
province
:
"Badghis"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some problems here:

1. You're setting the attributes to an "update" selection. This will not work (unless you call the function twice). It has to be:

   ```
   circles.enter()
       .append("circle")
       .attr("cx", function(d) {
       //etc...
   ```

   because of that, there were no circles in your SVG. However, changing that point #1 shows you two additional problems:
2. You're using a `scaleLog` with a domain that crosses zero. There is no `log` of zero (actually, it is minus infinity). As the API clearly says:

   > As log(0) = -∞, a log scale domain must be strictly-positive or strictly-negative; the domain must not include or cross zero.

   So, use a linear scale instead.
3. You are using the wrong property for the radii. It should be `rColumn`.
4. You forgot to set the range of the `rScale`.

All together, this is your (almost) working code:

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.3/leaflet.js">


</script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v0.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var outerWidth = 500;
  var outerheight = 250;
  var margin = {
    left: -50,
    top: 0,
    right: -50,
    bottom: 0
  };
  var xColumn = "longitude";
  var yColumn = "latitude";
  var rColumn = "population";
  var peoplePerPixel = 1000000;
  var innerWidth = outerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
  var innerHeight = outerheight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", outerWidth)
    .attr("height", outerheight);

  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate (" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, innerWidth]);
  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([innerHeight, 0]);
  var rScale = d3.scaleSqrt().range([1, 5]);

  function render(data) {
    xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d[xColumn];
    }));
    yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d[yColumn];
    }));
    rScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d[rColumn];
    })]);

    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);
    circles.enter().append("circle").attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(d[xColumn]);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale(d[yColumn]);
      })
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return rScale(d[rColumn]);
      });
    circles.exit().remove();
  }

  function type(d) {
    d.latitude = +d.latitude;
    d.longitude = +d.longitude;
    d.population = +d.population;
    return d;
  }


  var data = d3.csv(
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Pre60/myTest/master/map_cities.csv",
      type, render)

</script>
```

PS: There is no difference in writing `var data = d3.csv(url, callback)`, since `d3.csv` doesn't return anything (actually, it returns an object related to the request). So, just drop that `var data`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm new to this, really appreciate your help. Could you please tell me where I can find the API that you are talking about?